# Manually editing and deleting an entity - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

How do I manually edit and delete an entity in Symfony2?

I get that it creates a class, but how do I edit everything? I'm guessing I can't just change the PHP class file.

So which files does it create when you use the automatic entity generator and is there an automated-edit command? I use Yaml.

I know with bundles then you there are three files that the automated console command creates/changes, but I can't see any info as to how for entities.

I like to use the automation to save time, but still like to know actually what is being done etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your php code ( Entities code ) then just run

> php app/console doctrine:generate:entities BundleName:EntityName

you may also want to update your db by running

> php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: as far as a know there is no commad for deleting an entity, so you just have to delete it  manualy by deleting php class and yml files then update your db

Comment: I know with bundles, the console automatically adds some files but also EDITS some (e.g. app/AppKernel.php), does this happen with entities?

Comment: no, the console just verify you entities( if you got relationships) and generate setters an getters for your fields